# Find LRT and rejection

Tags: ratio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfG8B.jpg)
For each of the n independent individuals, there are two measures of interest:xi which is some known value, and Yi which is a random variable distributed as N(α+βdo,σ^2)

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.